# Parameter expansion won't work with variable

Tags: bash

I am trying to break this string `$line` into different sub-strings using parameter expansion.

```
# bool db/setting/accessibility/tts val="some value here"
line="bool db/setting/accessibility/tts val=\"some value\""
#
# step 1
data_type=${line%% *}
echo $data_type         #bool
remain_str=${line#"$data_type"} #this doesn't work
echo $remain_str                #db/setting/accessibility/tts val="some value"
remain_str=${line# *}           #this works
echo $remain_str                #db/setting/accessibility/tts val="some value"
```

I am follwing this guide http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073

How to do parameter expansion using variables instead of constant strings or characters & how can I use both at the same time ?

for example

when I use `remain_str=${line#"$data_type"}`
string should be stripped of the data type
and `echo $remain_str` should print `db/setting/accessibility/tts`

Comment: Hi ankit, please take a moment to edit your question and be absolutely clear about what is the question.

Comment: @shelter removing dbl-quotes not working. `eval` throws error
`./test.sh: line 8: db/setting/accessibility/tts: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 2):

Your code works as expected in sh, bash and dash:

```
#!/bin/bash
line="bool db/setting/accessibility/tts val=\"some value\""
data_type=${line%% *}
echo $data_type
remain_str=${line#"$data_type"}
echo $remain_str
remain_str=${line# *}
echo $remain_str
```

All three shells I checked produce the same output:

```
bool
db/setting/accessibility/tts val="some value"
bool db/setting/accessibility/tts val="some value"
```

And if I change the last substitution to `"${line#* }"`, I get the last line identical to the second.

Comment: It works fine when I put commands directly on shell but when I use a test.sh it doesn't work. its very strange.

Comment: Got it. `chmod 755` did it for me